# Three.js how to set different camera far value for each layers?

Tags: three.js

How to set different camera far value for each layers in three.js?

I want to cull some details like stones, grass. But not cull basic road, mountain in camera.

Like Unity`s layerCullDistances.

```cs
Camera camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
float[] distances = new float[32];
distances[10] = 15;
camera.layerCullDistances = distances;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [`camera.far` property](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.far). If you want to change the distance of the far projection plane, just set that value.

```js
var cam = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 1, 1000 );

cam.far = 90210;
```

Here I'm setting it to `1000` on the constructor, and then changing it to `90210` at some later point in time.

Comment: far property is for every layers which were enabled. But I want to define different far property for each layer.

Comment: @AeroXu That functionality doesn't exist out of the box. You'll have to manually modify it when updating layers.